# Find$\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n!}$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the sum of this alternating series with factorial denominator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185915/finding-the-sum-of-this-alternating-series-with-factorial-denominator)

Find$$\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n!}$$
I have tried Taylor series, but it does not have $x^n$. Is there any trick to solve the problem?

Comment: The basic solution is to replace $-1$ with $x$ and then substitute $-1$ back into the resulting formula

Comment: Would the voter to reopen care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
S_N & = \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \dfrac{(n+1)}{n!}\\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \left(\dfrac{n}{n!} + \dfrac1{n!} \right)\\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \dfrac{n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \dfrac1{n!}\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^n \dfrac1{(n-1)!} + \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \dfrac1{n!}\\
& = \left( -\dfrac1{0!} + \dfrac1{1!} - \dfrac1{2!} + \cdots + \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!}\right) + \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \dfrac1{n!}\\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac1{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \dfrac1{n!}\\
& = \dfrac{(-1)^N}{N!}
\end{align}
Can you now finish it off by letting $N \to \infty$?

Comment: Your original answer was better...

Comment: @wj32 But that had to do with manipulating infinite series, though it was legal. And anyways I do not see  much difference between the current answer and the previous one I had.

Comment: @Marvis From the 4th column to 5th column, how does$(n-1)! $becomes $n$.By substitute? Thanks : )

Comment: @PENGTENG Yes. It is just a change of variables $n \to n+1$. I have expanded it out to be clear.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n!}&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^nn}{n!}+\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}+\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{n!}\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is what?